# Environment texture using 180 degree zenith-centered orthographic projection

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, hdri

I'm trying to add sun halos into my renders that were generated using an ancient program called HaloSim, which hasn't been updated in 20 years but is the only program that does this. However, the only projections it has is is a fisheye projection (which I'm pretty sure is orthographic) and perspective. The orthographic projection is only 180 degrees, rather than 360, and when centered around the zenith, ends at the horizon (an example of one of these images is below (yes I am going to denoise and upscale it))

[image: 1]

I've been trying to figure out how I could add these into the environment texture and to have them be projected correctly, but I haven't yet found a way to do so. What's below the horizon doesn't matter, as long as the halo isn't distorted (or distorted as little as possible)